# Don't know how to get desired output with SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently trying to echo out the following fields for my php page

form_no (cepincident and occurrence table)

name (user table)

department (user table)

datetimeuploaded (cepincident and occurrence table)

datetimeupdated (cepincident and occurrence table)

I have 3 tables with the following information that I need.

occurrence table (1 forms inside)

[image: occurrence table]

cepincident table (3 forms inside)

[image]

and user table

[image]

For my desired output I'm supposed to get out 4 rows of data but I either keep getting 1, 3, a ton or just 0. I don't know what I'm supposed to do with my query.

Thanks. I'll try to provide more information as I go along.

My desired output is something like this [image]

I've tried this

```
"SELECT *  
    FROM users u 
    JOIN cepincident ci ON u.user_id = ci.author
    JOIN occurrence o ON u.user_id = o.author";
```

but my results came out like this

[image]

Comment: What is your desired output ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `cepincident` table is supposedly most frequently accessed.
In case of `cepincident` and `occurrence` tables  have to coincide by `form_no`,`datetimeuploaded` ,`datetimeupdated` fields:

```
"SELECT ci.form_no, u.name, u.department, ci.datetimeuploaded, ci.datetimeupdated   
    FROM users u 
    RIGHT JOIN cepincident ci ON u.user_id = ci.author
    LEFT JOIN occurrence o ON u.user_id = o.author
        AND o.form_no= ci.form_no;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying but the issue is that the ci and o tables have different values.

Comment: different? and from what table have you retrieving values for `datetimeuploaded `, `datetimeupdated` fields?

Comment: Hi I managed to solve it using 
"SELECT form_no, author, datetimeuploaded, datetimeupdated, department, name FROM cepincident, users WHERE author = user_id
        UNION
        SELECT form_no, author, datetimeuploaded, datetimeupdated, department, name FROM occurrence, users WHERE author = user_id";

Comment: The problem was that the ci and o tables although having the same fields, store different type of forms

Comment: your way works too thou, although I only managed to get 3/4 forms to display